# Characterising almost uniform convergence for step functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Exercise 3 of these [notes](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/) describes modes of convergence by showing their relationship with step functions converging to zero.

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Consider the sequence of functions $f_n = A_n 1_{E_n}$ where $A_n > 0$, $E_n \in \mathcal{M}$, and $\mu(E_n) > 0$ for all $n$. Define the $N$-th tail support of the sequence by $E_N^* = \bigcup_{n \geq N} E_n$.

Can anyone provide a proof that $f_n$ converges almost uniformly to $0$ if and only if $A_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ or $\mu(E_N^*) \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Is $A_n$ a function or a set? Also, what does $A_n>0$ mean? What notion of convergence is used for $A_n\to 0$?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker $A_n$ is a real number, which also pins down the notion of convergence. The definition of almost uniform convergence is as follows. For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a measurable set $F$ with $\mu(F) \leq \varepsilon$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $F^c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original exercise, there is an additional assumption (that cannot be dispensed with, as Byron Schmuland has shown):

> We also assume the $A_n$ exhibit one of two modes of behaviour: either
>   the $A_n$ converge to zero, or else they are bounded away from zero
>   (i.e. there exists $c>0$ such that $A_n\geq c$ for every $n$. It is
>   easy to see that if a sequence  does not converge to zero, then it has
>   a subsequence that is bounded away from zero, so it does not cause too
>   much loss of generality to restrict to one of these two cases.

The proof now becomes rather simple. It is very easy to see that $A_n\to 0$ or $\mu(E_N^*)\to 0$ are sufficient for  almost uniform convergence to zero.

For the other direction, assume that $A_n$ does not converge to $0$, but $f_n$ converges almost uniformly to $0$. Let $\epsilon>0$. There is a $F$ with $\mu F<\epsilon$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to zero outside $F$.

In particular there exists $N$, such that outside $F$, we have $f_n< c$ for $n\geq N$. But $$c 1_{E_n}(x)\leq A_n 1_{E_n}(x)< c$$ implies $1_{E_n}(x)=0$, hence $E_n\subseteq F$ for all $n\geq N$. This implies that $\bigcup_{n\geq N} E_n=E_N^*\subseteq F$, and hence $\mu(E_N^*)\leq\mu(F)<\epsilon$. Since  the $E_N^*$ are a decreasing sequence, this shows that $\mu(E_N^*)\to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the statement is quite right. Let $E_n$ be a decreasing sequence of measurable sets with $\mu(E_n)\downarrow 0$. Then the sequence 
$$1_X,\quad  1_{E_1}, \quad {1\over 2}1_X,\quad 1_{E_2}, \quad{1\over 3}1_X, \quad 1_{E_3},\quad {1\over 4}1_X,\,\dots$$ converges almost uniformly to zero, but $A_n$ doesn't converge and $E^*_N=X$ for all $N$.